# Browser back button doesn't work when return redirect push in reactjs component (only Chrome and Edge - in firefox is ok)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I have components like belows (not exactly like this but illustrates more or less the situation):

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <div>
            <Link to={'/home'} target="_blank">
              Home
            </Link>
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/home">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/error-500">
          <div>Error 500</div>
        </Route>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default App;

const Home = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return <ErrorHandler />;
};


const ErrorHandler = () => {
  return <Redirect push to={'/error-500'} />;
};

export default ErrorHandler;
```

Redirect component have **push** prop so the history should have 2 entries when new tab with '/home' is open and it has but in chrome and edge the back button is inactive.

The suprising fact is that in every browser from javascript it is possible to go back using:

```
window.history.back()
```

Can anyone has idea why back buttons in chrome and edge browser are inactive? In firefox everything works as expected.

Chrome:
[back button in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpy2x.png)

Edge:
[back button in edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQo0Y.png)

Firefox:
[back button in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJMiM.png)

You can preview this situation here: https://codesandbox.io/s/back-button-issue-fyjq9

Comment: Home opens on a new tab? Where does back take you in FF?

Comment: Yes Home is opened in a new tab, after 3s user is redirected (simulation of fetching data) and after that redirect to error-500. Back button causes return to home and after 3s is redirected again, but in real scenario there wouldnt be redirection because for example server now could return valid response.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem with you but I using history.pushState.
You can check the method of history.pushSate

Ex: history.pushState(state, title [, url])

If you don't want to reload the page, just put null/ empty string in `title`.
If you want to pass it, just type text in `title`

Link refer: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/js+redirect+without+reloading